# Collectd - Randomly Missing 'type_instance' Field

Tags: logstash, collectd

I use `collectd 5.4` along with `logstash`, `elasticsearch` and `kibana` for monitoring purposes on my Ubuntu 14.04 system. My `collectd` configuration file looks like this:

```
Hostname "my-host-name"

Interval 1

LoadPlugin cpu
LoadPlugin load
LoadPlugin df
LoadPlugin memory
LoadPlugin swap

LoadPlugin interface
<Plugin interface>
    Interface "eth0"
    IgnoreSelected false
</Plugin>

LoadPlugin network
<Plugin network>
    Server "127.0.0.1" "25826"
</Plugin>
```

The thing is that everyhing works perfectly fine until I enable the `df` plugin. With `df` plugin enabled I get missing `type_instance` field in the output of `memory` plugin. Here is the aforementioned output:

```
{"@version":"1","@timestamp":"2014-09-04T07:20:42.143Z","host":"my-host","plugin":"memory","collectd_type":"memory","value":6250332160.0}
{"@version":"1","@timestamp":"2014-09-04T07:20:42.143Z","host":"my-host","plugin":"memory","collectd_type":"memory","type_instance":"buffered","value":55103488.0}
{"@version":"1","@timestamp":"2014-09-04T07:20:42.143Z","host":"my-host","plugin":"memory","collectd_type":"memory","type_instance":"cached","value":1283186688.0}
{"@version":"1","@timestamp":"2014-09-04T07:20:42.143Z","host":"my-host","plugin":"memory","collectd_type":"memory","type_instance":"free","value":665567232.0}
```

Look at the first line of the given output. There's no `type_instance` field. The expected behavior is to have `"type_instance":"used"`. It is only happening with `used` field and it is happening randomly. And everything works fine until I enable the `df` plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this answer still helps. 
I had the same problem and solved by fixing logstash's collectd plugin. 
I used collectd 5.4.1 and logstash 1.4.2.

**1. Reason**

As you said the problem happens when you use df and memory plugin at the same time. 
Here's problem scenario.

Assuming collectd sets the following df and memory data sequentially in one UDP packet.

{"@version":"1","@timestamp":"2014-10-31T06:04:08.371Z","host":"example",**"type_instance":"used"**,"plugin":"df","plugin_instance":"root","collectd_type":"df_complex","value":5076176896.0}

{"@version":"1","@timestamp":"2014-10-31T06:04:08.371Z","host":"example",**"type_instance":"used"**,"plugin":"memory","collectd_type":"memory","value":7530356736.0}

collectd UDP protocol do not set the same data if it set it previously in a UDP packet (maybe to minimize packet size)

So, because collectd set "type_instance" as "used" in df data, it do not set "type_instance" again in memory data. (See protocol spec: https://collectd.org/wiki/index.php/Binary_protocol)

But logstash collectd plugin reset "type_instance" as blank when "plugin" value changes.

**2. How to fix the problem**

The collectd plugin is written in jruby. So you can fix the source easily. 
Edit lib/logstash/inputs/collectd.rb. 
Find the following 2 lines and fix them.

From:
411 line: @collectd.delete(k) if !['host', '@timestamp'].include?(k)
417 line: @collectd.delete(k) if !['host', '@timestamp', 'plugin', 'plugin_instance'].include?(k)

To:
411 line: @collectd.delete(k) if !['host', '@timestamp'**, 'type_instance'**].include?(k)
417 line: @collectd.delete(k) if !['host', '@timestamp', 'plugin', 'plugin_instance'**, 'type_instance'**].include?(k)

After fixing, the problem disappeared.

Answer (score 1):

The collectd input plugin has been deprecated since version 1.4 in favor of using the udp input plugin with the collectd codec.  The collectd codec has been refactored and does not have this issue.  It preserves type_instance between events until overwritten.